# NSByteCountFormatter no visible @interface

Tags: interface, selector, nsformatter

i've read that this error can be related to NSByteCountFormatter not supported by the target operative system.

This class is supported from version 10.8 (mountain lion).
So i changed my project "Deployment Target" from 10.6 to 10.8, but i stil get this error.

Tried with make clean, reboot, nothing.. 
I'm missing something?

```
NSByteCountFormatter *sizeFormatter = [[NSByteCountFormatter alloc] init];
[sizeFormatter includesUnit:NO];

//fileSizeMb is a NSString
fileSizeMb = [sizeFormatter stringFromByteCount:[fileSize longLongValue] countStyle:NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleFile];
```

**Error:**
*no @interface for 'NSByteCountFormatter' declares the selector 'stringFromByteCount:countStyle:'*

any idea?

Answer (score 1):

`+ stringFromByteCount:countStyle:` is a **Class** method. So you could either use

```
fileSizeMb = [NSByteCountFormatter stringFromByteCount:[fileSize longLongValue] countStyle:NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleFile];
```

but this will not have your desired countStyle. Or you change your code to

```
NSByteCountFormatter *sizeFormatter = [[NSByteCountFormatter alloc] init];
[sizeFormatter includesUnit:NO];
sizeFormatter.countStyle = NSByteCountFormatterCountStyleFile;

//fileSizeMb is a NSString
fileSizeMb = [sizeFormatter stringFromByteCount:[fileSize longLongValue]];
```

Comment: I will try your suggestion when i will finish this project, anyway at the moment i solved simply by using this 
`attribs = [fileManager attributesOfItemAtPath:atPath error:&error]; fileSizeMb = [[attribs objectForKey: @"NSFileSize"] doubleValue] / 1000 / 1000;`

Anyway thanks for your solution, i will definitely try that soon and tell you if it's working.